# Trouble Centering Text Link in HTML Table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am attempting to center text links above images in a simple table.  I am using an external style sheet for css, and have tried many things to simply center the linked text (Kinni Creek Lodge and River Guide Kayaks) with no success.  Here is a screencap of the table with borders to help visualize what is happening:

[image]

Here is the table HTML code:

```
<center>
  <table id="rentals">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://www.kinnicreek.com/" target="_blank">Kinni Creek Lodge</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://www.riverguidekayaks.com/" target="_blank">River Guide Kayaks</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="kinnicreeklogo.png" width="168px" height="140px"></td>
      <td><img src="riverguidelogo.png"></td>
    </tr>  
  </table>
</center>
```

And the CSS:

```
#rentals {
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
}

#rentals td {
  border-style: solid;
}
```

Edit (full code):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Explore the Kinni</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="slideshow.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<center><div id="bannerdiv">
<img src="banner.png" id="banner"></img>
</div></center>
<br><br>
<div id="background">

<div id="header">
Kayaking on the Kinni
<hr>
</div>

<p class="clear">

<div class="menu">
  <div class="menucontent">
    <a href="index.html">Home</a> 
    <a href="kayaking.html">Kayaking</a>
    <a href="fishing.html">Fishing</a>
    <a href="hiking.html">Hiking</a>
    <a href="skiing.html">Skiing</a>
    <a href="info.html">Other Information</a>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="content">
<p>There are many businesses in town that offer kayak rentals and guides! Kayak trips can last from one to six hours, and have challenges for beginning and advanced kayakers.  The trips have a wilderness-like experience as the river has been well preserved.</p> <br>
<h1>Rental Companies</h1><br>

<center>
  <table id="rentals">
    <tr>
      <td><a href="http://www.kinnicreek.com/" target="_blank">Kinni Creek Lodge</a></td>
      <td><a href="http://www.riverguidekayaks.com/" target="_blank">River Guide Kayaks</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><img src="kinnicreeklogo.png" width="168px" height="140px"></td>
      <td><img src="riverguidelogo.png"></td>
    </tr>  
  </table>
</center>

<h1>Tips</h1>
<p>Do not bring anything that you would not want ruined.  Items that are brought along on the river will most likely get water on them (including you!).  Make sure to put electronics into a waterproof bag that floats.  Additionally, bring food and espicially water for the mutliple-hour trips.  One final recommendation is to <i>not</i> where flip flops as they will float away.
</div>

<div id="slideshow">
   <div>
     <img src="kayakingpics/image1.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="kayakingpics/image2.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="kayakingpics/image3.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="kayakingpics/image4.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="kayakingpics/image5.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="kayakingpics/image6.jpg">
   </div>
   <div>
     <img src="kayakingpics/image7.jpg">
   </div>
</div>

<p class="clear">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
  /* background: linear-gradient(#323A40, #272d32); */
  background-image: url("background.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

body {
}

#background {
  background-color: rgba(153, 102, 34, .4);
  background-size: cover;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border-color: #222211;
  border-style: outset;
  height: auto;
}

#bannerdiv {
}

#banner {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
  width:800px;
  margin-left: 250px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 350%;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px #664422;
}

hr {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-left: 150px;
  width: 500px;
  border-color: #332200;
}
.menu {
  background-color: #ccbbaa;
  width: 245px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.menucontent {
}

.menucontent a {
  display: block;
  padding: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #222211;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.menucontent a:hover {
  background-color: #222211;
  color: #bb9944;
  border-color: #664422;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
}

.content {
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 17, .7);
  height: 2000px;
  width:800px;
  color: #bb9944;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  float: left;
}

.content a {
  color: #bb9944;
  margin-left: 4em;
  font-size: 150%;
}

p.clear {
    clear: both;
}

p {
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#rentals {
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
}

#rentals td {
  border-style: solid;
}

#slideshow { 
    margin-left: 5px;
    position: relative; 
    width: 470px; 
    height: 400px; 
    padding: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.8); 
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#slideshow > div { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 10px; 
    left: 10px; 
    right: 10px; 
    bottom: 10px; 
}
#slideshow img {
  height: 400px;
  width: 470px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #664422;
}
```

Comment: with this code it is centering for me, do you have any other css applied to the images? https://jsfiddle.net/szzqdrsh/

Comment: Please don't use the `<center>` element. It was deprecated in HTML4 and removed from HTML5.

Comment: I do not believe so.  I will update the post will my full code.

Comment: Columns are usually left-aligned by default. Either the `center` tag is messing things up, or you have some left margin on your links. Try adding `text-align:center` to your `#rentals td` rule.

Comment: you have margin-left in your .content a tag, take that out and it should work

Comment: That was it!  Thanks for the help everybody - and I'll also make sure not to use <center> in the future.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to center an element within it's parent.  The simplest is to set the child  to the value **margin: 0 auto;** what this does is set the top/bottom margin to zero and the right/left value to equal each other.
Another way is to use flexbox. Set the parent  to **display:flex; and justify-content:center**

Here are two sites which should help-
https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Hopefully this helps

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you:

Add this line in css:

```
table#rentals tr td{text-align:center}
```

Comment: Either make is into a comment (which you cannot do yet) or improve the answer and add info on why this works